# Verify string does NOT contain a value other than known values [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, string, logic

I am trying to verify that a string contains nothing but known values. In this case, I need to make sure it contains only "Shift", "Control", or "Alt", but not necessarily all of those. For example, these should be true: "Shift + P", "Shift + Control + H", "Alt + U; but these should not: "Other + P", "Shift + Fake + Y", "Unknown + Shift + E" etc.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
If Not shortcut.Contains("Shift") Or Not shortcut.Contains("Control") Or Not shortcut.Contains("Alt") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid")
End If
```

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the needed logic to do this. I'm assuming there's a logic operator that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should not use strings for this purpose. You need a data type that can represent a hotkey combination, which is comprised of a "normal" key and a set of modifiers (Alt, Control, Shift), each of which can either be on or off. The on/off modifiers can be represented by an enum with flags, and the "normal" key can be represented by a separate enum. Both of the enums can be contained within a class.

The [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) enumeration can be used as both enums. You can store two numeric values (one for the modifiers, one for the "normal" key) - the underlying enum values - and they will represent the combination. No need to store strings.

If you do use strings for this purpose, you need to define your constraints better. Your rules do not specify how "Shift + Other" is invalid, but "Shift + F" is. A way to go about this, anyway, is to separate the string by " + " (assuming this is always the separator) and then compare each part to the list of valid values, which apparently contains "Shift", "Alt", "Control" and all single letters.

Comment: I'm loading this from a CVS file. I can change the storage method to separately store each modifier and the key, but I'd like to understand what logic is involved in this. Regarding point 2, the last "value" is always a key; the others are modifiers, of which "Shift", "Control", and "Alt" are valid.

Comment: I edited the answer to suggest a way to validate the string, but I still think you should use a better fitting data type.

Comment: I also added a suggestion for an alternative storage method. I hope this explains it better.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of the proper storage method. Storing the values as strings and then trying to parse them out is unnecessarily difficult when you could store them as simple integer values, mapped to a pre-existing enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to split the string into segments and then iterate through the list of words and then comparing to what words should exist. This is in C# but I guess you could figure it out.

C#:

```
        string text = "Shift+Control+Alt+Other";
        string[] textSegments = text.Split('+');
        string[] allowedWords = { "Alt", "Shift", "Control" };
        foreach (string t in textSegments)
        {
            bool temp = false;

            foreach (string t2 in allowedWords)
            {
                if (t == t2)
                {
                    temp = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!temp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Right!");
            }


        }
```

The output will be 4 MessageBoxes displaying: "Right!" "Right!" "Right!" "Wrong!"